# Definite integral of a rational function

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^6-x^3}{(2x^3+1)^2}dx$$

I tried integrating but the problem keeps on dividing into many smaller problems which would take a lot of time to solve. Please give some hints on how to integrate easily. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: You might want to start to aim at $$\int\frac{x^6-x^3}{(2x^3+1)^2}\,dx=-\frac{x^4}{2(1+2x^3)}+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{1+2x^3}\,dx.$$ For the last term, I think you cannot avoid logarithms and arctans.

Comment: User 1upon0 Is your question is $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^6-x^3}{(2x^3+1)^3}dx = -\frac{1}{36}$ which user5713492 have mention below.

Answer (score 1):

It might be best to improve the denominator in a couple of steps.
$$\frac d{dx}\frac1{2x^3+1}=\frac{-6x^2}{(2x^3+1)^2}$$
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{x^6-x^3}{(2x^3+1)^2}dx&=\int_0^1-\frac16(x^4-x)\frac d{dx}\frac1{2x^3+1}dx\\
&=\left.-\frac16\frac{x^4-x}{2x^3+1}\right|_0^1+\frac16\int_0^1\frac{4x^3-1}{2x^3+1}dx=\frac13-\frac1{2^{4/3}}\int_0^{2^{1/3}}\frac{du}{u^3+1}\end{align}$$
Where the integrated term worked out to $0$ and we have used polynomial long division and then the substitution $2^{1/3}x=u$ to simplify the integrand. Next it's time for partial fractions,
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{du}{u^3+1}&=\int\frac13\left[\frac1{u+1}+\frac{-u+2}{u^2-u+1}\right]du\\
&=\frac13\int\left[\frac1{u+1}+\frac{\left(-u+\frac12\right)+\frac32}{\left(u-\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}\right]du\\
&=\frac13\left[\ln(u+1)-\frac12\ln(u^2-u+1)+\sqrt3\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2u-1}{\sqrt3}\right)\right]+C\end{align}$$
So
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{x^6-x^3}{(2x^3+1)^2}dx&=\frac13-\frac1{3\cdot2^{4/3}}\left[\ln\left(2^{1/3}+1\right)-\frac12\ln\left(2^{2/3}-2^{1/3}+1\right)\right.\\
&\left.+\sqrt3\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2^{4/3}-1}{\sqrt3}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt3}\right]\end{align}$$
All quite pedestrian stuff. While confirming this result numerically, I made a mistake and found out that
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^6-x^3}{(2x^3+1)^3}dx=-\frac1{36}$$
And that makes me wonder whether I am missing some kind of simplification in the topical integral.

**EDIT**: There doesn't seem to be any special reduction. After integration by parts the integral with the cube reduces to a rational function:
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{x^6-x^3}{(2x^3+1)^3}dx&=\int_0^1-\frac1{12}(x^4-x)\frac d{dx}\left(\frac1{(2x^3+1)^2}\right)dx\\
&=\left.-\frac1{12}\frac{x^4-x}{(2x^3+1)^2}\right|_0^1+\frac1{12}\int_0^1\frac{4x^3-1}{(2x^3+1)^2}dx\\
&=-\frac1{12}\left[\frac{x^4-x}{(2x^3+1)^2}+\frac x{2x^3+1}\right]_0^1=-\frac1{36}\end{align}$$
But it is possible to tidy up the original integral to
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^6-x^3}{(2x^3+1)^2}dx=\frac13-\frac1{3\cdot2^{4/3}}\left[\frac32\ln\left(\frac{2^{1/3}+1}{3^{1/3}}\right)+\sqrt3\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2^{2/3}-1}\right)\right]$$